# How to limit a list by the a maximum div height?

Tags: php, html, css

We have a `div` that is fixed through:

```
.example_class{
    height:340px;
    width:340px;
}
```

Now we should display a list in that `div`. The list is generated according to a MySQL-Query. It should display as many elements as possible that are whole.

My issue now is that because of the fixed size there will be a line-break when the text is too long. This is intended behaviour but prevents me from just displaying x-elements. Cutting the text off after a certain length is also not allowed.

Do I have to count the number of letters for each MySQL-string that I got? Or what other options do I have?

**EDIT** Here how the list-entries are generated:

```
<div class="example_class">
    <h3>Jobs</h3>
    <ul>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= count($getTopTenJobs); $i++) { ?>

            <li> <?php echo $getTopTenJobs[$i]['fld_title']; ?> </li>

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What would you want to happen if even a single (very long) entry cannot fit? Do you format your list with HTML, like with `li` tags? How do you otherwise visually separate  entries? Can you show your relevant PHP code?

Comment: Looking at your case there are too many restrictions, you have to compromise/adjust somewhere. Either you increase the height of the `div` which will accommodate all the text which is dynamic or show limited text only with `...` at the end which later you can expand or show it in the tooltip or something. Or you have to change the way of representation.

Comment: @trincot I updated the question with how the list is generated

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar I was hoping for a property where I could define how many lines should be visible in a div. Sort of like max-height but so that it includes the List in the div as well

Comment: you could put `overflow-y:auto` in the CSS properties. Then the div would show a scrollbar when there's too much text to fit in the area

Comment: @Gildraths I've added my answer, just let me know if you're looking for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot know where the overflow will happen, since it depends on the font, different character widths, and even the zoom-level of the browser. And still when all these factors are the same, the overflow status might still be different across browsers.

So you need some post-processing in JavaScript, which will detect the overflow and then clip the contents until there is no more overflow.

To do that, add this script just before the ending `</body>` tag:

```
<script>

(function clip() {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.example_class');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];
        var ul = div.querySelector('ul');
        while (div.scrollHeight > div.clientHeight && ul.children.length) {
            var li = ul.children[ul.children.length-1];
            ul.removeChild(li);
        };
    }
})();

</script>
```

This will visit all those `div` tags on the page and check for each if there is an overflow. If so, repeatedly the last `li` is removed until there is no more overflow (or there are no more children).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, It will calculate your `div` height and also each `li` height and keep only those `li` which are fit in the div.

I've deducted `50` from the `div` height for margin purpose. Let me know it is helpful for you.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sum = 0

    $('.example_class ul li').each(function () {

        sum += $(this).height();

        if (sum > Number($(".example_class").height()) - 50) {

            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```